# XML nodes duplicating when one is added

Tags: c#, xml

About a year ago, I started on a project that pulled comics from the internet, and you could store your favorites in an XML file. It worked perfectly until recently, when I started having some problems with the file paths that I fixed easily.

The favorites are displayed in a ComboBox with two buttons: "+" and "-".

For some reason, now when I press the + button, the ComboBox duplicates everything in there and adds the new comic once. The XML file just shows what it would normally show, however added comics and removed comics don't have any effect.

Could this be related to the file paths that I changed, some kind of goof that I could have ignorantly made, or something else that could have happened?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to clear() the combobox before reloading the list from the XML.